# Crop image & show the right (as in: not-left) part

Tags: css

I'm "cropping" a image (let's say cropping because not the whole image is displayed):

```
  .carousel img {
        max-width:300%;
        width:150%;
        min-height: 300px;
  }
```

[image]

But now the left part is shown, but i would like to show the right part, is this possible? Preferably without setting the img as background for a div.

EDIT:

Css:

```
/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.carousel .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.carousel-control {
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 120px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
}
.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
 }

 @media (max-width: 979px) {

  .carousel {
    margin-top: -20px;
  }

  .carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
  }
  .carousel img {
        max-width:300%;
        width:150%;
        min-height: 300px;
        align: right;
        float: right;
  }
```

It works all fine on the min-width: 979px; devices.

HTML:

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img align="right" src="assets/img/slider/slide-01.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Title.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Text</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   ...
```

Comment: Well `position:right` isn't a valid property in CSS

Comment: was just experimenting something, removed it

Comment: is the image in a div with a set size?

Comment: Only a static height and a 100% width

Comment: So what is the width. Is it auto?

Comment: What happens to the overflow of the image? Is it hidden? Could you possibly show some HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this css on the holding div and html:

```
.carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/6XcHC/1/

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effect

Comment: really look at my fiddle

Comment: Your fidle doesn't work for me, (maybe my browser) but for some strange this seems not to work in my situation, assuming a direct copy and paste

Comment: New fiddle also seems to have no effect.